# Obtain content of <script src="..."> tag in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11

I have an HTML file with Javascript, that is supposed to load and process an XML file. The main obstacle is that the script may also be run locally, without an HTTP server, and also has to support Internet Explorer (11).

In normal case, I would use XMLHttpRequest, but as far as I know, it cannot be used with locally stored files (or at least doesn't work in my test cases for Chrome and IE).

I tried using `<script>` blocks with set `src` and `type="text/xml"` attributes and it successfully loads the content of the xml "somewhere" (the content is loaded and is visible in the network trace), but I cannot find a way, to extract the content of the xml from the `<script>` node.

Most sources (e.g. [Getting content of <script> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139724/getting-content-of-script-tag)) suggests using XHR, but AFAIK it cannot be done in this case.

Is there a sensible option to implement this, without minimal http server?

I am looking for a clean solution without jQuery.

Comment: It is possible to request files at `file:` prototcol at chromium, chrome [Read local XML with JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41279589/read-local-xml-with-js/41401418?s=1|2.2411#41401418); not sure about ie

Comment: "At the moment, due to the security policy Chromium can not read local files via ajax without --allow-file-access-from-files." -- this is a deal-breaker in my case.

Comment: You can include the contents of the file within the `html` of the `document`