# Get content of a external script included on page

Tags: javascript

I have a script include on a page as following.

```
<script src="https://domain/demo.js" type="text/html" id="google_script"></script>
```

Once the `demo.js` is loaded, I need to grab the content of loaded demo.js without recalling it with ajax. Please share your thoughts if that's possible and how.

Answer (score 2):

## Sadly no.

With pure JavaScript you can't get content of other JavaScript file without executing it.

**Possible solutions:**

- [Use PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)
- Save your JS file as text file and then [load it to iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4534000/5364144) and get the source
- [Get the source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4862987/5364144), but **run the script**

**EDIT:**
With JavaScript you can't get full script, but function like:

```
var funcsourcecode = functionname.toString();
```

Comment: `functionname.toString();` is enough to me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use php helper is better, like mentioned already. But... sometimes ts is possible when CORS allows.

If you do not append inner scripts to document but override, then it will not be executed. So, you must convert external scripts to inner:

```
function isScriptExternal (scriptElement, oldSrc) {
    if (!oldSrc) {
        oldSrc = scriptElement.src;
    }
    return (!!oldSrc && (oldSrc[0] != '#' || oldSrc.startsWith('#external/')));
}

function getExtrnalContent (url) {
    var xmlHTTP = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (window.location.href.startsWith('https:') && url.startsWith('http:')) {
        url = 'https:' + (url.substring('https:'.length));
    }
    xmlHTTP.open('GET', url, false); // sync!
    xmlHTTP.send(null);
    if (xmlHTTP.status !== 200) {
        throw new Error('Error loading by ajax: ' + url);
    }
    return '' + xmlHTTP.response; // -- CONTENT IS HERE
}

function getInnerContent (scriptElement) {
    if (!!scriptElement.innerHTML) {
        return '' + scriptElement.innerHTML;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}

function setInnerContent (scriptElement, newContent) {
    scriptElement.type = 'text/javascript';
    scriptElement.innerHTML = newContent;
}

function scriptToInner (scriptElement) {
    console.log('!scriptToInner:');
    if (!scriptElement || !scriptElement.tagName || 'SCRIPT' !== scriptElement.tagName.toUpperCase()) {
        console.warn('It is not script!');
        return;
    }
    var oldSrc = scriptElement.src;
    if (!!oldSrc && oldSrc[0] === '#') {
        console.warn('Avoid repeat: ' + oldSrc);
        return;
    }
    scriptElement.removeAttribute('src');
    if (!isScriptExternal(scriptElement, oldSrc)) {
        setInnerContent(scriptElement, '/*Patched inner:*/\n' + getInnerContent(scriptElement));
    } else {
        try {
            scriptElement.src = '#external/' + oldSrc;
            setInnerContent(scriptElement, '/*Patched external: "' + oldSrc + '"*/\n' + getExtrnalContent(oldSrc));
        } catch (e5) {
            setInnerContent(scriptElement, '/*!Patch error*/');
            scriptElement.src = oldSrc;
        }
    }
}

let scripts = document.querySelectorAll('script');
for (let script of scripts) {
    scriptToInner(script);
}
```